# What's the difference between "transferir" and "trasladar"?

Tags: selección-de-palabras, sinónimos

Looking at the RAE dictionary definition, [trasladar](http://dle.rae.es/?id=aRlZFZd) and [transferir](http://dle.rae.es/?id=aJH8a9T), there doesn't seem to be much of a distinction between them other than that *trasladar* could be used to mean "to reproduce a copy".

Is there any significant distinction in usage between the two?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, there is a difference.

"Trasladar" means "to move", "to relocate", while "transferir" means "to transfer".

Although the definitions in the DRAE can be similar, people understand them very differently. "Trasladar" means basically "pick one thing, move it, and place it at its new location".

"Transferir" usually implies a "change of medium", like while you transfer information (info - digital pulses - receiver) or when a light beam is transferred to another medium, and so on.

Comment: So which word would you use when you talk about transferring money or ownership of something like a house?

Comment: @C.J.Jackson - If you want to move funds from one account to another, I think you could use either one.  But if you want to shift ownership of a house, I think you have to use "transferir," because "trasladar" would sound as though you're relocating the house from Point A to Point B.

Answer (score 1):

Transferir se refiere a cosas "no físicas" y son cosas poseídas por alguien, como conocimiento, que pasan a alguien más.

> Ejemplo: Le han transferido el derecho de criar a los niños

Y trasladar es para cosas "físicas"

> Ejemplo: Tu padre y yo nos trasladamos a otra ciudad.

Puedes **trasladar** un mueble, puedes trasladar un auto de un lugar a otro.

Puedes **transferir** un conocimiento, puedes transferir el derecho de posesión de algo.

**Resumen:**

Transferir tiene mucha relación a cosas que te pertenecen. Transferencia son posesiones **no físicas** que pasan de una persona a alguien más.

Mientras que trasladar es solo el mero hecho de "mover algo" algo que es "**físico**"

Es mi humilde conocimiento, que creo que te puede servir, eso es lo que yo tengo entendido.

Comment: Genial primera contribución. Bienvenido a [Spanish.se]. Espero seguir viendo más contribuciones tuyas en el futuro!

Comment: tambien se refiere a los trabajos: por ejemplo, me trasladaron a otro departamento.